# Flex mobile text from hidden TextInput still visible

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, fonts, textinput

I have weird bug with Flex TextInputs. I'm using Flex 4.9.0 in my Android app. App has view navigator in group component. I add custom popup by inserting it as a child of that group. Popup covers view in view navigator and everything seems fine. Unfortunently text from TextInputs in view is still visible and selectable. How is this possible? I thought that depths in Flex are sacred :/ I've embed font, but that hasn't changed anything.

Here is the image with this bug.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're using the "StageText" TextInput skin.  It is always on top of everything else.  You have to switch to the Flash TextField TextInput skin.

I wrote an in depth [blog post](https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/5/1/Why-does-a-TextInput-appear-above-my-Popup-in-Flex-46) on this.  The work around is to switch back to the old TextInput skin:

```
<textInput skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin" />
```

Comment: @Reboog711 - are you familiar with any workarounds for issues with  spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin - https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3292370

Comment: @flexicious.com The Flash TextField doesn't support the same properties that StageText does; so as such I Don't believe there are any work-arounds.  [Unless Adobe Flash/AIR have changed the internals]